# Espaçamento no JSX

Tags: javascript, jsx

Estou com um arquivo JSX e preciso da um espaço entre o  `{item.payment.bucket}` e `OU`. No HTML seria mais ou menos assim:

```html
{item.payment.bucket} &nbsp; OU.
```

Meu código JSX:

```js
<ValueDiv>
    <Icon src={require("../../images/icons/img-cash.png")}/>
    {item.payment.bucket}
    OU
    <Icon src={require("../../images/icons/img-ball.png")}/>         
</ValueDiv>
```

Comment: por favor verifique as resposta e assinale uma como resposta do seu post

Answer (score 3):

Você pode imprimir uma string com um espaço (`{' '}`) para dar **um** espaço.

```js
const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <strong>Sem</strong>
    <em>Espaços</em>
    
    <hr />
    
    <strong>Com</strong>{' '}
    <em>Espaços</em>
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Se você quiser dar múltiplos espaços, pode utilizar o `&nbsp;` normalmente:

```js
const App = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <span>Múltiplos</span>
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    &nbsp;
    <span>Espaços</span>
  </React.Fragment>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Show de bola, conseguir!!! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se entendi a sua pergunta, mas se o que você está tentando fazer é adicionar um espaço dentro de um texto pode fazer assim:

```
<Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{'    '}Debug{' '}</Text>
```

Ou pode criar uma view vazia com o tamanho do espaçamento que tu precisas, por exemplo se quiser um espaço horizontal:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Componente1>
        //conteúdo
    </Componente1>
    <View style={{height: <tam espacamento> width: < tam espacamento>}} </View>
    <Componente2>
        //Conteudo
    </Componente2>
</View>
```

Aconselho a criar um componente no teu projeto para colocar espaços em qualquer lugar:

```
function Spacer(props) {
  return <View style={{height: props.size, width: props.size}} />;
}
```

Podendo usar assim:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Componente1>
        //conteúdo
    </Componente1>
    <Spacer size={16}/> //16 Como exemplo de tamanho para o espaçamento desejado.
    <Componente2>
        //Conteudo
    </Componente2>
</View>
```

Se não for isso, por favor replique. ;)

Comment: é isso mesmo!! Obrigado!!!